# How can I add photo to my menu?

Tags: android, image, menu, listactivity

I am working on an android app, got a menu, just wondering if it is possile to add photo next to each menu elelment

Also another question, currently the menu is covering the whole screen, because using "extends ListActivity" and not having a layout I guess.
How can I add an ImageView on the top of screen or any other types of views?

Code:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

String classes_names[] = { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
String classes[] = { "class1", "class2", "Class3" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes_names));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Class ourClass;
    try {
        ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.app." + classes[position]);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you looking similar as http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Comment: No :(, that is an action bar

Comment: to add image next to item in listview .. you need the baseadapter to create the custom Row.. also you can set the onclick on each item: http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android/  hope this help you to solve 1st Queation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SimpleAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter - it has a method setViewImage() along with setViewText() method. But if you want to make customization in your listview items you have to extend some of the Adapter classes and override getView() method
If you need to make your listview occupy just part of your layout you have to create XML file for your layout and to call method setContentView passing your XML file as an argument

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Is it possible to show it in code? thanks

Comment: First create layout resource file for your view, somewhere in it declare Listview widget. Then in onCreate() method after call of super call setContentView(id of your layout resource). Then declare Listview variable and pass to it reference to your Listview. Then on your ListView call method setAdapter and pass to it new SimpleAdater

Comment: Sorry I can't write code from mobile but you can take a look at this example http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/listview-simpleadapter/